# Bind value to the dynamically generated div in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 buttons namely period, lunch and break. When I click any of these button the div id generated dynamically based on the button click.

I have written a `onclick` for each 3 button and inside the click event I am creating dynamic divs.

For the first click of button-period it creates a new div and calculating the period start time and end time and binding these value to dynamical created div.

**but my problem is that if I do second click on the same button, new div is generated but the value is not binding but instead its overriting the first div. How can I bind the data to the generated div.**

```
<button id="btn-period">PERIOD</button>
<button id="btn-lunch">LUNCH</button>
<button id="btn-break">BREAK</button>
<div id="period-container"> 
</div>

    $("#btn-period").click(function(){
        var periodTime = localStorage.getItem("totalMins");
        var f=periodTime.split(".");
        var perHour = f[0]; //total minuts after split

        $("#period-container").append('<div class="period-div"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-4"><span id="perid-text">PERIOD</span></div><div class="col-md-4"><span id="perid-stime"></span></div><div class="col-md-4"><span  id="perid-etime"></span></div></div></div>')
        var endt = $("#hdVal").text();//fetching endtime of prayer
        var funOutput=calculate(endt,perHour);//test for end time of prayer 
    });
    $("#btn-lunch").click(function(){
    var lunchTime = localStorage.getItem("lunch");
    $("#period-container").append('<div class="lunch-div" style="background-color: #5bc0de; color: #fff; box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px grey; padding: 10px; margin-top: 10px;margin-bottom: 10px;"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-4"><span id="perid-text">LUNCH</span></div><div class="col-md-4"><span id="perid-stime"></span></div><div class="col-md-4"><span  id="perid-etime"></span></div></div></div>')
  });
    $("#btn-break").click(function(){
    var breakTime = localStorage.getItem("breakduration");


    $("#period-container").append('<div id="" style="background-color: #f0ad4e; color: #fff;    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px grey;padding: 10px;margin-top: 10px;margin-bottom: 10px;"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-4"><span id="perid-text">BREAK</span></div><div class="col-md-4"><span id="perid-stimes"></span></div><div class="col-md-4"><span  id="perid-etime"></span></div></div></div>')

});

function calculate(endTimes,perHour)
{
    alert("dsd");
    $("#perid-stime").html(endTimes);
    var d=endTimes.split(":");
    var min= (+d[0]) * 60  + (+d[1]);
    var few=parseInt(min) + parseInt(perHour);
    var num = few;
    var hours = (num / 60);
    var rhours = Math.floor(hours);
    var minutes = (hours - rhours) * 60;
    var rminutes = Math.round(minutes);
    $("#perid-etime").html(rhours +" : "+ rminutes);
    $("#hdVal").text(rhours +" : "+ rminutes);

}
```

Currently I am calling calculate function only in period but I want to call same function for rest of the 2 button click.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

plz check this https://jsfiddle.net/qd1r03wk/

your issue is in setting all div with the same id, instead, I just only creates div with unique,

```
$("#btn-period").click(function(){
        var periodTime = localStorage.getItem("totalMins") || "8.00";
        var f=periodTime.split(".");
        var perHour = f[0]; //total minuts after split
                var periodLength = $(".period-div").length;
        $("#period-container").append('<div class="period-div"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-4"><span id="perid-text'+periodLength+'">PERIOD</span></div><div class="col-md-4"><span id="perid-stime'+periodLength+'"></span></div><div class="col-md-4"><span id="perid-etime'+periodLength+'"></span></div></div></div>')
        var endt = "12:30";// $("#hdVal").text();//fetching endtime of prayer
        var funOutput=calculate(endt,perHour,periodLength);//test for end time of prayer 
});
```

plz note that I had commented out your variable `endt` and `localstorage` value

Comment: i wil try bro:)

Comment: var periodTime = localStorage.getItem("totalMins") || "8.00"; why did u wrote 8:00 here

Comment: I don't have the localstorage value, so I just added a fallback, so that if localstorage is empty it assign "8:00" to variable `periodTime`

Comment: plz check the fiddle it also has changes in `calculate` function as well

Comment: sure bro i wil check:)

Comment: its overriting. still the same response.

Comment: plz check this https://jsfiddle.net/qd1r03wk/1/ , if not then plz update your code in the fiddle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162948/discussion-between-noushad-mohammed-and-aswin-ramesh).

Answer (score 0):

You are creating divs with same ID on button-period click event.

In `calculate(...)` function you are set html for `perid-etime` div only.

The solution is you have to generate divs with different IDs and same IDs you have to use in `calculate(...)` function to update text/HTML.

Comment: how do i create id according the button clicked

Comment: You can take one variable and append that variable to the IDs of div. Pass same variable to the `calculate(...)` function and use that variable to update text/HTML of the variable like below.  `$("#perid-etime" + variable).html(rhours +" : "+ rminutes);
    $("#hdVal" + variable).text(rhours +" : "+ rminutes);`